# Correct way of writing "Lying is unforgivable" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-identification

I'm curious if "Mendacium est irremissibile" is correct or even close, or would it be rearranged to "Mendacium irremissibile est"

Answer (score 3):

Your suggestion *Mendacium est irremissibile* is certainly correct Latin and just about means what you want it to. It would indeed be more common to put *est* at the end.

Two comments:

- Strictly speaking, *mendacium* does not mean “lying,” it means “lie, falsehood.” <sup>1)</sup> So your sentence really means “A lie is unforgivable.” Not much of a difference.
- *irremissibilis* is a Church Latin expression. A classical alternative would be *inexpiabilis*.

With more context you could also use a verbal expression, e.g. *Contumeliis indulgebo, dummodo verae sint, mendacia vero si dicuntur, nullo modo ignoscere possum.*

<sup>1)</sup> But note that some P. Nigidius was of the opinion that *Inter mendacium dicere et mentiri distat. Qui mentitur ipse non fallitur, alterum fallere conatur; qui mendacium dicit, ipse fallitur.* (There is a difference between telling a falsehood (*mendacium*) and lying. One who lies is himself not deceived and attempts to deceive another; one who tells a falsehood is himself deceived. A. Gellius: [Noctes Atticae 11, 11](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/gellius/gellius11.shtml)). However, this kind of sophistry was not observed by the everyday Latin speaker.